# How to fetch picklist using Eloqua rest Api

Tags: eloqua

I have a form in Eloqua which I need to translate in my project. I have added checkboxes/radiobuttons and the options are used from picklist. I am able to fetch all the fields except the picklist. How can fetch the picklist using Rest Api so that I can send them out for translation?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a single picklist by id using the [Retrieve an option list Application API endpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-rest-1.0-assets-optionlist-id-get.html), or you can retrieve a list of picklists using the [Retrieve a list of option lists Application API endpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-rest-1.0-assets-optionlists-get.html).